# Trying to pass an array to a method but throws incompatible types error?

Tags: java, arrays, incompatibletypeerror

I'm trying to design a program that creates an array and then populates it in one method, calculates the average in another method and then will print its contents and the average in the main method. However I get an incompatible type error when trying to pass the array to the calAverage method and do not understand why.

```
public class week3d
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
    int [] list = new int [20];
    list = fillArray();
    int average = calAverage(list); // this is where the error occurs


    System.out.println("The average of this list is "+average/20);
}

public static int [] fillArray()
    {
    int [] a = new int[20];
    for (int i =0;i <20;i++)
    {
    a[i] = i*10;
    System.out.println(a[i]);
    }    
    return a;
}

public static int [] calAverage(int[] a)
{
    int average = 0;
    for (int i =0;i <20;i++)
    {
    average += a[i];
    }   
    return average / 20;
    }
}
```

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Comment: Also : no need for  `int [] list = new int [20];     list = fillArray();` . Do  `int [] list =  fillArray();`

Comment: Up voted your question. I wonder why people down-vote new users (without an explanation) thus discouraging new users.

Comment: you are right @c0der

Comment: Your method return type is array (i.e. int[ ]), but you are actually returning int. Hence the error

Answer (score 1):

The program shows the message: `Incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int`.

This is because the return type of the method `calAverage()` is `int[]`, i.e., it returns an integer array. But you want it to return an `int` value as the variable `average` in `calAverage()`, whose value is returned, and the variable in the main method that gets its value assigned as the value returned by `calAverage()` are of type int. So, change the return type of `calAverage()` from `int[]` to `int`.

```
public static int calAverage(int[] a)
{
    int average = 0;
    for (int i =0;i <20;i++)
    {
        average += a[i];
    }   
    return average / 20;

}
```

Comment: @C.Dodds Please maek an answer as the correct one if you have found a solution to your problem.

Comment: Up voted for @C. Dodds who probably is not familiar with SO conventions yet (0: